Setup Nginx Reverse Proxy with Upstream SSL
I need to setup a reverse proxy with Nginx with Upstream SSL.
Nginx server should act as LoadBalancer and SSL endpoint.
Upstream backend {
ip_hash;
server 192.168.178.11;# here no ssl
server 192.168.178.12;# here no ssl
}

server {
        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

I want to get all traffic to nginx server with ssl. The nginx server will do also loadbalancing to the backend servers. But the communication between nginx server and backend servers should be http (no ssl).
Both backend servers are needs no persistance since they provide api based functional service.
How can I setup the traffic without https which is between nginx server and upstream backend servers?

What is the problem with this config? Looks like what you want.

I would ask that if I need to specify no ssl by writing special ports on backend servers. And also which proxy_set_header(s) should I set? And is there any thing to do hardening it ?

There is non need for try_files. And usually you should add proxy_set_header Host $host; Other that that this config looks fine.
